# how to check the Disk drive problems in windows?

Tags: hard-drive, windows, drive

In a windows server the alloted space for a drive is 450 GB( for example drive G:). But the drive show full all the time. shows 449 GB is used and 1 GB free space. I tried chkdsk with no help. When I try to defragment it ended up with error by giving the message run chkdsk in the drive. How can i identify the problem and set this resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Refer the below URL from sysinternals to check the disk issues with the help of utilities mentioned at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545046.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should attempt to backup all your data now creating an ASR backup.

When you ran chkdsk disk did you do it while the system was booting?

Answer (score 0):

Use the windirstat utility to find what is using up all your space and clear it off.  Try to have at least 25% free space on the drive.  Then run `chkdsk /f`

With only 1GB free space on a 450GB volume you will surely be having performance problems as well as inviting file system corruption.  It won't be possible to defragment the volume without having more free space.

Answer (score 0):

If the windows server isn't currently running anything mission critical and you suspect there may be physical drive issues, you should use the manufacturer's drive utility run from a live CD like the [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/).

If you believe the disk issues to be related only to fragmentation, you could use a third-party defragmenter like [Defraggler](http://www.piriform.com/defraggler) or [UltraDefrag](http://ultradefrag.sourceforge.net/).  A list of defragmentation alternatives to the Windows utility are listed [here](http://alternativeto.net/software/windows-disk-defragmenter/).